# rgeolocate error - country for each IP address

Tags: r, geolocation, ip-address, maxmind

I cannot get rgeolocate to work properly. I need to be able to determine if an IP address is in Australia or not.

I have a list of IP addresses in a csv. However I have provided a sample code below and get the following error:

```
Error in maxmind_(ips, normalizePath(path.expand(file)), fields) : 
  Not compatible with STRSXP: [type=list].
```

I have googled and searched for a solution to this but nothing I have found has worked to date and I would really appreciate it if anyone knew the solution.

The rgeolocate package has successfully downloaded and the GeoLite2-Country.mmdb appears to be where it should be within the extdata folder.

```
library(rgeolocate)

ip_lst <-
  data.frame(
    "ip_lst" = c(
      "27.33.27.39",
      "203.219.204.84",
      "203.5.106.68",
      "180.150.74.11",
      "193.116.238.48",
      "1.157.7.35",
      "61.69.150.57",
      "155.143.204.211"
    )
  )

file <- system.file("extdata","GeoLite2-Country.mmdb", package = "rgeolocate")
results <- maxmind(ip_lst, file, c("continent_name", "country_code", "country_name"))
results
```

I have tried multiple versions of the Maxmind code unsuccessfully. Grateful in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a data frame called **ip_lst** containing one variable called `ip_lst`, which is not wrong, but it can be confusing. The problem here is that the `maxind` function is expecting a character *vector*, but you are supplying a data frame. So the following should work:

```
maxmind(ip_lst$ip_lst, file, c("continent_name", "country_code", "country_name"))

  continent_name country_code   country_name
1        Oceania           AU      Australia
2        Oceania           AU      Australia
3        Oceania           AU      Australia
4        Oceania           AU      Australia
5         Europe           GB United Kingdom  # <-- Not an Aussie 8(
6        Oceania           AU      Australia
7        Oceania           AU      Australia
8        Oceania           AU      Australia
```

Comment: your time is greatly appreciated. I do feel like a bit of a numpty! Thanks ever so much.

Comment: Yes, just type: `results$ip.address <- ip_lst$ip_lst`. BTW, I'm a UNSW alumni. :D

Comment: I just figured it out and deleted the second request! Wonderful Edward thanks so much. I've been working here for about 3 years now......its great. Hope life outside UNSW is going well. Thanks again.